# What's the difference between @Secured and @PreAuthorize in spring security 3?

Tags: spring-security

It's not clear for me what is the difference in spring security between :

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
 public void create(Contact contact)
```

And

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
public void create(Contact contact)
```

I understand PreAuthorize can work with spring el but in my sample, is there a real difference ?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

The real difference is that `@PreAuthorize` can work with [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html). You can:

- Access methods and properties of [`SecurityExpressionRoot`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.html).
- Access method arguments (requires compilation with debug info or custom [`ParameterNameDiscoverer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/ParameterNameDiscoverer.html)):

  ```
  @PreAuthorize("#contact.name == principal.name")
  public void doSomething(Contact contact)
  ```
- (Advanced feature) Add your own methods (override [`MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/method/MethodSecurityExpressionHandler.html) and set it as `<global-method-security><expression-handler ... /></...>`).

Comment: Didn't know about this, but seems awesome! :D

Answer (score 64):

If you wanted to do something like access the method only if the user has Role1 **and** Role2 then you would have to use @PreAuthorize

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_role1') and hasRole('ROLE_role2')")
```

Using

```
@Secured({"role1", "role2"}) // is treated as an OR
```

Answer (score 49):

Simply,
`@PreAuthorize` is newer than `@Secured`.

So I say it is better to use `@PreAuthorize` as it is "expression-based" and you can use expressions like hasRole, hasAnyRole, permitAll, etc.

To learn about expressions, see these [example expressions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/el-access.html).

Answer (score 21):

`@PreAuthorize` is different, it is more powerful than `@Secured`.

- > The older `@Secured` annotations did not allow expressions to be used.
- > Starting with Spring Security 3, the more flexible annotations
  >   `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` (as well as @PreFilter and
  >   @PostFilter) are preferred, as they support Spring Expression
  >   Language (SpEL) and provide expression-based access control.
- > `@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")` annotation is the same as `@PreAuthorize ("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")`.
- > The `@Secured({"ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN")` is considered as ROLE_USER **OR** ROLE_ADMIN.

so you cannot express the AND condition using

> **@Secured**. You can define the same with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') OR hasRole('USER')")`, which is easier to
>   understand. You can express **AND, OR, or NOT(!)** as well.
>
> **@PreAuthorize**("!isAnonymous() AND hasRole( 'ADMIN')")

Comment: As you reverted my edit, are you saying that there is no error in this `"hasRole('ADMIN OR hasRole('USER')"`?

Answer (score 12):

```
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                               |                         @Secured                         |                         @PreAuthorize                           |
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Spring EL expressions                         | Does'nt supports.                                        | Supports                                                        |
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Multiple roles conjunctions with AND operator | Does'nt supports.(If there are multiple roles defined    | Supports                                                        |
|                                               |they will be automatically combined with OR operator)     |                                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| To enable annotation                          | Add following line to spring-security.xml                | Add following line to spring-security.xml                       |
|                                               | <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" /> | <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>        |
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Example                                       | @Secured({ROLE_ADMIN , ROLE_USER})                       | @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') and hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") |
|                                               | public void addUser(UserInfo user){...}                  | public void addUser(UserInfo user){...}                         |
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```