# Spring security - How to assign security roles to small groups?

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm using spring security and have wired it successfully to authenticate users based on roles defined in the authorites table.

I've then protected my resources using AOP eg.

```
<security:global-method-security >
        <security:protect-pointcut expression="execution(* com.test.testService.*(..))" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED"/>
</security:global-method-security>
```

all is well.

But I'd like to be able to use spring security to secure a users access to a particular articles editing rights. There is a boolean flag on a record a user created and only they should be able to access it otherwise a spring security exception should be thrown.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @PreAuthorize annotation may work for you. It takes Spring EL and you can provide access based on a property in principal. Please see [What's the difference between @Secured and @PreAuthorize in spring secu 3 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785706/whats-the-difference-between-secured-and-preauthorize-in-spring-secu-3).

Comment: Thanks Ritesh. I shall try this and report back.