# Criteria based authorization check with spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

How does spring security support dynamic role & permission? For example, the role can be generated at runtime by end users. Each role can include multiple permissions which can be created/updated at runtime. Each permission is base on criteria like delete topic if no activity for 3 months. The ACL of spring security can't support it since records of acl_entry are static instead of dynamic.  How to customize spring security to support such requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security 3 supports [expression based authorization](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-pre-post-annotations): it allows you to express secuirty constraints as arbitrary expressions in [Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html). By default you can use methods of [`SecurityExpressionRoot`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.html) in these expressions.

However, you can add your own methods by customizing [`MethodSecurityExpressionHandler.createEvaluationContext()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/method/MethodSecurityExpressionHandler.html), so that you can define arbitrary criteria and use them in these expressions. Also see [What's the difference between @Secured and @PreAuthorize in spring secu 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785706/whats-the-difference-between-secured-and-preauthorize-in-spring-secu-3/3786581#3786581) ?.