# Spring security @Secured and @PreAuthorize

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, annotations, spring-security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between @Secured and @PreAuthorize in spring secu 3 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785706/whats-the-difference-between-secured-and-preauthorize-in-spring-secu-3)

I'm wondering which annotations is more correctly to be used with spring security - `@Secured` or `@PreAuthorize`. It seems that `@Secured` is Java ee5 annotation but I saw more examples with `@PreAuthorize` rather then `@Secured`.

Comment: as suggested, flagged as duplicate