# Spring security different roles DTAP

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-el

We currently have different roles in our environments, for example in development we have roles called `USR` and `ADM`, while in production they use full names for example `USER`, `ADMIN` and `ADMINISTRATOR`.

My idea to resolve this problem is to use a property file and a placeholder for the rolenames, for example, this is my properties file:

```
role.user='USER'
role.admin='ADMIN', 'ADMINISTRATOR'
```

In my `AppConfig` I added the following annotation on top of the class:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:roles.properties")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

And in my service I'm now using:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole(${role.admin})")
public Item deleteItem(int id) {

}
```

However, this results in the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 12): Unexpected token.  Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lcurly({)'
```

---

Because it says it's not expexting the curly brace, I also tried the following: `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole(role.admin)")` which results in:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 11): Property or field 'role' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot' - maybe not public?
```

At least the expression itself looks valid now, but it seems it's not looking at the properties file no, but at a property of a specific class.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this? Or is there another/better solution of resolving environment-specific roles?

Comment: I would translate role names right when they are read. Or alternatively you can use role hierarchy.

Comment: Btw. `${}` is format for property placeholder. For SpEL you might want to try `environment['role.admin']`.

Comment: The `environment['role.admin]` isn't working either, it gives the same exception (it's looking for `environment` in `MethodSecurityExpressionRoot`. I'll try the other options later (take some more time to implement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring EL used in @PreAuthorize does only have:

- Access to methods and properties of SecurityExpressionRoot.
- Access method arguments (requires compilation with debug info or custom ParameterNameDiscoverer):

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786581/883859

You can get access to other beans via `@` so

```
 public interface RoleNameGetter {
    String getSuperUserRole();
    ...
 }
```

And

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource("classpath:xyz.properties")
 @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
 public class Configuration {
    @Autowired
    protected Environment env;

    @Bean
    RoleNameGetter roleNameGetter() {
      return new RoleNameGetter() {
        @Override
        public String getSuperUserRole() {
            return env.getProperty("superuser_role_name");
        }
    };
}
```

Allows for access to role names from the property file in the Spring EL used in @PreAuthorize, like this:

```
  @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority(@roleNameGetter.getSuperUserRole(),@roleNameGetter.getNormalUserRole())")
  public void end() {...}
```