# Java Spring - Annotation param as a property value

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Java - Spring Annotation param from property value

Following is my `@Secured` annotation i want to define string "USER_ABC" in .properties file and use it over here like `@Secured({myProp})` but it gives me error

```
@Value('${my.property}') private string myProp;

   @Secured({myProp,"ADMIN_123"})
    public void mySecureMethod(){
    }
```

instead of

```
@Secured({"USER_ABC","ADMIN_123"})
public void mySecureMethod(){
}
```

any solution appreciated in advance.

Comment: It is my understanding that annotation parameters must be [constant expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). What you're trying to do is not one of those unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't use `@Secured` because as Edwin points out, it can't handle constant expressions, you can use the `@PreAuthorize` annotation which will evaluate an SPEL expression.

Just be aware that `@PreAuthorize` works slightly differently in terms of the Spring Security Filter chain and when it gets invoked.

There is a very good question that should probably be your first port of call [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785706/whats-the-difference-between-secured-and-preauthorize-in-spring-security-3). If there is some reason why you can't use `@PreAuthorize`, let me know.