# When should we use @PreAuthorize and @Secured

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, annotations, spring-annotations

I read this stackoverflow post
[What's the difference between @Secured and @PreAuthorize in spring security 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785706/whats-the-difference-between-secured-and-preauthorize-in-spring-security-3)
However,I am still not clear as to what is the big difference between the two in terms of security? In what scenarios should we go for @PreAuthorize as compared to @Secured?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@PreAuthorize` allows you to get a more fine-grained control on the rules to secure o method. You can use SpEL expression inside of it.

Securing a method with `@Secured` gives you the same result as `@PreAuthorize` but the `@Secured` is limited and you don't get as much options to tweak the rules (a gross simplification it's that the rules are "static").

> Spring Security 3.0 introduced the ability to use Spring EL expressions as an authorization mechanism in addition to the simple use of configuration attributes and access-decision voters which have seen before. Expression-based access control is built on the same architecture but allows complicated boolean logic to be encapsulated in a single expression.
>
> - http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

Comment: So there is no difference if I replace  @Secured("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") with @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") , with respect to security features.

Comment: @Zack: You can't use `hasRole` with `@Secured`. You can only say `@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})`. The `hasRole` means executing a method with SpEL. `@Secured` does not have support for SpEL.

Answer (score 5):

`@PreAuthorize`is a newer version, so you should always go with `@PreAuthorize`, which is indeed better for the reasons mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785706/whats-the-difference-between-secured-and-preauthorize-in-spring-security-3).

And in fact

`@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")` is identical to  `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")`

In addition, @PreAuthorize syntax is more readable.

e.g. 
`@Secured({"ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"})` is treated as `ROLE_USER` `or` `ROLE_ADMIN`, which is something weird and confusing.

On the other side with `@PreAuthorize` you use the "Spring Expression Language (SpEL)" where you define explicitly `or`, `and` expressions, which is obviously convenient and more readable.

So go with `@PreAuthorize`.

Comment: So how do you specify AND logic in Secured annotations if OR is the default there