# How to populate the @Secured() annotation using values from a properties file?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-annotations

I can always do a `@Secured("ROLE_A", "ROLE_B")`. But is there a way to populate the `@Secured` annotation values from a properties file? Something like `@Secured({property_a}, {property_b})`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [@PreAuthorize](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PreAuthorize.html). You can put an Spring EL expresssion compare to @Secured which is limited.

Example :

```
@PreAuthorize("#n == authentication.name")
Contact findContactByName(@Param("n") String name);
```

Reference :

1) [What's the difference between @Secured and @PreAuthorize in spring security 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785706/whats-the-difference-between-secured-and-preauthorize-in-spring-security-3)

2) [Spring EL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html)